# Elasticsearch filter by terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm collecting a test runtime execution, so I have an index with these fields:

- `testName`: name of the test. There are multiple tests.
- `testDurationSeconds`: how much time the test run, in seconds.
- `buildNumber`: *Jenkins* job number, for example.

Now I want to calculate the *Average* of the `testDurationSeconds`, per `testName`. **But only if the test run in the last `buildNumber`**.

(For simplicity, let's say I have the last `buildNumber`.)

My aggregation right now looks like this:

```json
"aggs": {
    "byTestName": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "testName.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byBuildNumber": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "buildNumber"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "testDurationSeconds"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I filter it to eventually **get the `average` of `testName>testDurationSeconds` for all `buildNumber`s, only if the `testName` run on the specific `buildNumber`**?

(Worst case, I accept to get the list of `testNames` that meets the requirement above by a different aggregation, and compare the lists in an applicative way).

---

**Mapping:**

```json
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "buildNumber": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "testDurationSeconds": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "testName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example:**

```json
[
    {
        "testName": "Test1",
        "testDurationSeconds": 10,
        "buildNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "testName": "Test1",
        "testDurationSeconds": 20,
        "buildNumber": 2
    },
    {
        "testClass": "Test1",
        "testDurationSeconds": 30,
        "buildNumber": 3
    },
    {
        "testClass": "Test2",
        "testDurationSeconds": 10,
        "buildNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "testClass": "Test2",
        "testDurationSeconds": 20,
        "buildNumber": 2
    }
]
```

Let's say the last `buildNumber` was `3`. I want to get the average of `Test1>testDurationSeconds` (it should be `20`), but since the `Test2` is not run in the last run, I want to ignore it.

The best result will return the average of `Test1` only, but another result can return a list of tests that run in the last build (`3`) in another aggregation, in order to use that list to take the only relevant averages in the app level.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share you mapping and some sample data.

Comment: Have you tried using `avg_bucket` yet [avg_bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html)

Comment: By having `size: 10000` at the top- and sub-level you're going to have an issue at runtime by exceeding the `max_bucket` limit, which by default is 10000. You should really restrain those sizes if you don't want to run into performance issues.

Comment: @TrungDuc Yes, I'm actually using it in my real case, but I can't see how it can help with my problem. It is only averaging the bucket, but not filtering

Comment: @skap Added mapping and example